# Generate large dynamic forms with React, which do not re-generate on each input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm rewriting a form generator from a class based to a functional based approach. However, in both approaches I'm running into the same problem.
The form receives a field template, and values, loops the field specifications, and renders the appropriate inputs. Each is given it's value and a handler to carry the value in a state object of the form (which later can be submitted).

This works fine while the form is small, but of course those forms are not small and can grow to be quite large and many types of elaborate fields in them.  When the form field specification grows, the form slows down to the point where there is a delay between key press and visible input. Interestingly, that delay is very noticable while in development but is much better when compiled to a production build.

I would like to render the form elements as few times as possible and prevent the whole building of the form every time a key is pressed. However, if i pre-generate the fields, the event handlers don't retain the modified values. If I rebuild it on every render - it just slows things down.

A simplified example of this is here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/black-meadow-wqmzt

Note that this example starts by pre-rendering the form content into state and rendering it later. However, you can change the `render`s return line (in `main.js`) from :

`return <div>{formContent}</div>;`

to

`return <div>{build()}</div>;`

to have the form re-build on each render. You will notice in this case that the build process runs a lot.

Is it possible to pre-render a set of inputs with event handlers attached and retain the event handler's behaviour?

Edit: The slowness of a large form rendering is manifested in the input - typing some text into a text field for example sees a delay between keypress to rendering of the input because each key press triggers a rebuild of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use local state [and handler] to force item update/rerenderings. This of course duplicates data but can be helpful in this case.

```
export default function Text({ spec, value, onChange }) {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(value);
  const handleChange = ev => {
    onChange(ev);
    setVal(ev.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <label>{spec.label}</label>
      <input type="text" name={spec.name} value={val} onChange={handleChange} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

[working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-shadow-b9sil)

**BTW - use `key` (and not just index value) on outer element of item rendered from an array:**

```
  return (
    <div key={spec.name}>
      <FormElement
        spec={spec}
        value={values[spec.name] || ""}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
```

Comment: So this actually works and this brings me back a full circle almost (it was like this originally). Each field has a wrapper that renders the actual component. If i hold the state in that wrapper and carry the value upwards it kills the slowness and i can achieve a single render of the form! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should defer eventHandlers and all the behavior to React. I've simplified your code a bit here: https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-tree-1hxd2. All the changes are in `main.js` file. Below I explain what I changed and why.

- Removed useEffect hook and trigger of build() in there. Your hook was called only once on the first render and wasn't called on re-renders. That caused values don't update when you changed state.
- Added unique `key` to each field. This is important for performance. It let's React internally figure out what field has updated and trigger DOM update only for that input. Your build() function is super fast and don't have side-effects. You shouldn't worry that it is being called more than once. React may call render multiple times and you have no control over it. For heavy functions you can use useMemo (https://usehooks.com/useMemo/) hook, but it isn't the case here, even if you have 50 fields on a form.
- Inlined calls to `handleChange` and `fields`. That's minor and personal preference.

I don't see any delay in the code now and render called once or twice on each field update. You can't avoid render because it is controlled component: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components. Uncontrolled components isn't recommended when using React.

Final code for form component:

```
export default function Main({ template, data }) {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(data);

  console.log("render");

  return (
    <div className="form">
      {template.fields.map((spec, index) => {
        const FormElement = Fields[spec.type];
        const fieldName = spec.name;
        return (
          <div>
            <FormElement
              spec={spec}
              value={values[fieldName] || ""}
              key={spec.name}
              onChange={e => {
                setValues({
                  ...values,
                  [fieldName]: e.target.value
                });
              }}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: First, thanks! Second, this is what I was hoping to avoid - the re-rendering on each change to inputs. This code is a hyper-simplified and very small version of my actual code. Re-rendering the whole form in my case becomes slower as the form becomes bigger (though this is an issue in a development hot-reload build , and less so in a production).  
What I was hoping is to render once but have the fields retain input and handlers. This update is like `build()` each time. This results in a slowdown which is visible when i enter input into the fields - it has a delay between key press and render

Comment: If you see a visual delay on input then most likely you either have some complex state computation or render is triggered multiple times due to something. If you use `key` field then re-render will be fast when you change only one field's value. Try to debug what's going on. If you have a really heavy computation that doesn't depend on state: use Memo hook (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo). That will guarantee it computes only when dependencies change.

Comment: Yes, no doubt it's a complex thing. The actual form has over 20 fields, some textual, some more complex custom selectors, some live lookups etc. The whole thing renders dynamically into two columns, and fields can be moved around. Each field has a wrapper and they are all 'keyed'. But it does the re-render every key press which makes the whole thing sluggish (it actually runs ok on production builds but not on dev ones).